# How to call ListView adapter from another activity for refresh - notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, call, adapter

I want to call a listview adapter from another activies after insert record to sqllite db.

I cant call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method. What is the best way to do it.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView item_name;
    item_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.eItemName);         
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.add_item(new Item(item_name.getText().toString()), getApplicationContext());

    // I want to call the method HERE!!!! 

    finish();   
}
```

Comment: if there is no instance to that activity, how can you change data set?  You can start the activity manually and in the activity's onCreate, update the list items from DB.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

After `finish()` Current Activity, Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from `onActivityResult()`in previous Activity (As I assumes your Listview in this previous Activity).

Also start your Current Activity from Previous Activity using `startActivityForResult();`

Or if you have reference of List Adapter in this Activity, then using that reference call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. (But I think its not a good practice)

Comment: Dear @user370305 I have two activity, ItemsActivity and ItemsAddActivity and I'm start the ItemsAddActivity this codes:

`private void prepareListener() {
  listener_open_add_item = new OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ItemsAddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);    
   }
  };  
 }
`
I tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after startActivity(intent); line. But it didn't work. Cas the line is run before AddItemActivity finished. For the reason I try to run code after finish(); in that method.

Comment: Now instead of `startActivity(intent)` use `startActivityForResult(intent,0);` and add `onActivityResult()` method  in  ItemsActivity. in  `onActivityResult()` method write `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I added this codes but it seems onActivityResult method couldn't call. I still trying...

Comment: Debug your code of `onActivityResult()` because if you start an activity with `startActivityForResult()` and when this Activity finish() then method `onActivityResult()` of previous activity definitely called.

Comment: I tried but activity has never called. I create a button and after insert a record I clicked the button. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); command doesn't run. I think I try to reload ListView component or I try to add inserted record to adapter.

Thank you for your useful advices

Comment: onActivityResult called now with this code:

`@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  Log.d("RWatcher", "notify ok");
 }`

But ListView is still same. It doesn't refresh.  :)

Comment: Then just setAdapter() to ListView again in onActivityResult() with modified data list.

Comment: It's work now :) 

    `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         getItemList();  
    }
    public void getItemList() {  
        ArrayList<Item> itemArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
        itemArray = db.getAllItems();
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.items_row, itemArray);
        ilistViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

The better option would be re-loading your `ListView` with new data inside `onResume()` of your Activity where you have ListView. There is no need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from another class as you don't have your List visible in your another Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //fill your Collection with new data
    // setAdapter or notify your adapter
}
```

Comment: thx for your suggestion. It's work fine. 
But I think I re-loading ListView when call the method. Cas notifyDataSetChanged isn't work.

Comment: `@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
public void getItemList() {     
    ArrayList<Item> itemArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    itemArray = db.getAllItems();
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.items_row, itemArray);
    ilistViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
}`

Comment: Well I insisted to notify your adapter inside `onResume()`

Comment: I tried one more time. The result is negative. Listview doesn't refresh.

`@Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     Log.d("RWatcher", "notify ok");
 }`

Comment: make sure that you add new data to collection before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I sure new data added before calling. I tested diffirant way. I put a button for refresh data with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But listview didn't refresh again. Maybe the reason is the listView about database adapter.

Comment: are you populating List from database?